# Carbon 2 Date parsing returns different results

Tags: php, php-carbon

So Im getting a date from a url like this `2020-05-23` And Im trying to parse it into a carbon object so this following peace of code works fine

```
 $newDate = Carbon::parse('2020-05-23');
 dd($newDate);
```

that returns this:

```
Carbon\Carbon @1590192000 {#279 ▼
   date: 2020-05-23 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

what is correct but when I am trying to get the first and last day of this month it changes the variable?

```
$newDate = Carbon::parse($date);
//dd($newDate);
dd($newDate, $newDate->firstOfMonth(), $newDate->endOfMonth());
```

it returns then this

```
Carbon\Carbon @1590969599 {#279 ▼
   date: 2020-05-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00)
}
Carbon\Carbon @1590969599 {#279 ▼
   date: 2020-05-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00)
}
Carbon\Carbon @1590969599 {#279 ▼
   date: 2020-05-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

so it changes the date towards `20202-05-31` ? and the `->firstOfMonth()` returns the same as `->endOfMonth` Im not parsing the the date correctly?

also when I change the `Carbon::parse('2020-05-23')` toward `Carbon::now()` it works fine but with different date of course

Comment: Cannot reproduce, but I am not using `dd()`

Comment: It even works nicely in February, a leap year?

Comment: What your code does, rather depends upon whats in `$date` are you sure what that variable contains?

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right. This is working for me as well. Try it in Tinker (`php artisan tinker`). Output can be seen here https://i.imgur.com/FuHJ9L0.png

Comment: $date is in this case the variable out of the url that is send to the controller in laravel in case a string `2020-05-23`

Comment: in `php artisan tinker` @tamrat im getting the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date instance is `mutable` it means when you do something like `$newDate->firstOfMonth()` it will change `$newDate`

You can read this in the introduction of the documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-introduction

So when you do

```php
dd($newDate, $newDate->firstOfMonth(), $newDate->endOfMonth());
```

It will execute `firstMonth()` and then `endOfMonth()` before passing the parameters to `dd()` and since `$newDate` is mutable, the parameter content will be three time the end of month.

What you can do instead is

```php
dd($newDate, $newDate->copy()->firstOfMonth(), $newDate->copy()->endOfMonth());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Carbon::Parse` returns a mutable object. It means the methods will change the object you are working with instead of returning a new object and keeping the original intact.

When you call `dd`, PHP must first prepare 3 arguments so it calls both methods on the object with the last one changing the date to the last day of the month.

If you want the object to be immutable you have to use `CarbonImmutable`

```
$newDate = CarbonImmutable::parse($date);
dd($newDate, $newDate->firstOfMonth(), $newDate->endOfMonth());
```

See here for more informaion: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem And I can not figure out why it happening?

But when only doing `dd($newDate->firstOfMonth())` it works fine and returns the first date but when adding `$newDate->endOfMonth()` to make it `dd($newDate->firstOfMonth(), $newDate->endOfMonth())` it return twice the value of `$newDate->endOfMonth()` what is weird? and I dont know if this is an error in laravel carbon or just php

same for `var_dump`

Comment: The parent class `DateTime` has no issues https://3v4l.org/QjYEH